# Captcha not working in php , smarty

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, recaptcha

I am trying to implement a captcha in my web site , but it is always giving an error
incorrect-captcha-sol.

Please see my code

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if ($resp->is_valid) {
            echo "You got it!";
    } else {

            echo "Error=". $resp->error;
    }
```

Please check here [It is an Ajax call](http://shoarmagroningen.nl/restauranttoevoegen.php)

Comment: You have two reports of `[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector` in your JavaScript console. Not sure if that's relevant, but worth looking into.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the function declaring, not in its use

Comment: sorry I did not get you. Could u plz explain ...

Comment: Do u mean error in recaptchalib.php  ?

Comment: Have you checked the VALUES that is sent to the recaptcha_check_answer()-function ? ($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])

Comment: Are you using your own library to do the AJAX call? If so, I would recommend a JSON response, so you can temporarily add in arrays of useful data from the server (i.e. what response it was expecting).

Comment: hmm, let me see, hmm, no.

Comment: I have updated the code , and printed the $_POST array , please check it

Comment: Can u see that printed array ?

Comment: (You need to address individuals here by the way, e.g. @Pinky, otherwise people will not know who your messages are intended for - nor will they get a notification).

Comment: Sure @halfer , I will keep it in mind . Could u plz help me to find out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the sending of data in `validateCapture` is broken. Currently you have this in your AJAX call:

```
data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField +
    "&amp;recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
```

This results in a debug variable dump of this:

```
Array
(
    [recaptcha_challenge_field] => 03AHJ_VuskQR9VZwr6Uo5DllF4CL1GHDLajHiTQGHI3SE2pryBlSW-BMVeWMAudfOaTmOZu8vAPx5DaYjFoIjxhursn-GnXQwGA4T8Mn1rLL7E8Vrz-xVRs9c4c0-Gb9FxFhlNjy257xiTmvWikzjmRfsa9I3PZQcDSwgDu7Gq6A_RBC9NrV-cyqw
    [amp;recaptcha_response_field] => capture ceptICA
)
```

The key for the second one looks quite wrong, as it includes the encoded ampersand. You can probably swap the `&amp;` for a non-urlencoded value of `&`, but I would tend to prefer this:

```
data: {
    recaptcha_challenge_field: challengeField,
    recaptcha_response_field: responseField
}
```

This is a *hash* of the same data, and somehow that feels cleaner. Try that?